# How can i keep a log of how many Facebook likes a page has?

Tags: php, facebook

I want to rank my pages by the ammount of Facebook likes they have (via the facebook like api). Is there any way for me to automatically insert a value to mysql via PHP when the like button is clicked? Or a way for me to collect the ammount of likes for a page then insert that value? Is there anyway of doing this with the Facebook API? Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can subscribe to the edge.create event:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {
  // update database using Ajax here or something else...
});
```

I have never tested that but it should work according to FB's documentation.

Comment: would be nice if someone can post some experience with this code/method